# How to place two elements inside of an hexagon in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the shape of a hexagon and round corners, now, I would like to place to divs/input fields inside it.

CSS:

```
.hex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 10em;
  height: 17.32em;
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  background: orange;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.hex:before,
.hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}

.hex:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hex:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="hex">
    // divs or inputs elements here
  </div>
```

if I place something inside in the div it breaks the shape of hexagon.

P.S: if you have seen any login form which has a hexagon shape with round corners please send a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the inner content in an element and make it `absolute` and then position it. So that the hexagon shape doesn't break.

```css
.hex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 10em;
  height: 17.32em;
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  background: orange;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.hex:before,
.hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}

.hex:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hex:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hex span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
  <div class="hex">
    <span>// divs or inputs elements here</span>
  </div>
```